# Problems with exec "$@" in sh file

Tags: python, shell, unix, kubernetes, sh

I'm using a sh file to launch some other commands from a *jupyterhub_config.py* file, which it basically recreates a pod for a user.

The issue seems to be here in sh file that I have refactor best to my knowledge.

```
echo "Executing the command: $@" 

exec "$@" & tail -f /var/log/logShell/logInShell.log

echo "External user startup script finished"
```

The expected behavior would be that the commands passed to "$@" gets executed, and then the logs that are in *logInShell.log are* shown in the shell. However, the logs are never shown in shell despite the file having several lines.

From what I have read, running `exec` will replace the subprocess, which it makes me think that also replaces the shell and that's why the result of tail is never seen in the current shell.

Once the pod is running, I can see the tail command running using `ps -A`. However, the logs are never gotten to the shell at all. Does anybody knows what would be the right way to get the run tail in the current process or shell?.

Comment: `exec "$@" &` doesn't really make sense. `exec` _replaces the current process_, thereby terminating the shell that started it. You can't do that in the background, and once it's done, the shell is no longer running, so your last `echo` is never expected to be reached. You _can_ do `(exec "$@") &`, but it's just the same as just `"$@" &`, so I don't know why anyone would ever bother.

Comment: If you want to start a background process, just use `"$@" &` -- leave out the `exec`

Comment: It could happen that tail is started before the logfile is created, too. Also, `tail -f` will never finish.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt. ...good point; extended my answer showing how to work around that with GNU tail.

Comment: I suspect you're confusing `exec` with `eval`

Comment: @Barmar, ...though `eval` isn't appropriate for use in the scenario at hand either...

Comment: Mind, the "startup script finished" won't be written until after `tail` exits, so that's not really expected to ever be reached at all absent something surprising happening.

Comment: `exec ... &` forks first, *then* executes `exec` in the forked shell. It's a micro optimization that would keep an additional shell process hanging around that won't be used after the intended command completes, and one that may not be necessary as I believe `bash` already uses `exec` if it sees that its only command is a simple executable.

Answer (score 0):

Leave out the `exec` keyword. You may also want to monitor when the main program you're wrapping exits, and shut down `tail` if/when that happens.

```
#!/bin/sh

# warning: this is not actually echoing the same thing as the command you're running
echo "Executing the command: $@" 

# --follow=name --retry makes tail behave right even if the log is only created
# after tail's startup is complete; requires GNU extensions
"$@" & main_pid=$!
tail --follow=name --retry /var/log/logShell/logInShell.log & tail_pid=$!

wait "$main_pid"; main_rc=$?
echo "External user startup script finished"
kill "$tail_pid"
exit "$main_rc"
```

---

Now, about why `echo "Arguments are: $@"` is actively misleading / worse than useless:

Consider `./yourscript "first word" "*" "last word"` -- the quotes around `first word` and `last word` are critical to understanding the command line correctly; same for the quotes around `*`.

However, `echo "Arguments are: $@"` runs `echo "Arguments are: first word" "*" "last word"` -- which writes on output `Arguments are: first word * last word`, **completely destroying the record of where the quotes were in the original command**.

If your shell is bash, zsh, or sufficiently modern ksh, this is a nonfatal problem: Instead of `echo "Arguments are: $@"`, you can use:

```
# bash only
printf -v args_str '%q ' "$@"
echo "Arguments are: $args_str"
```

...or, with bash 5.0 or newer:

```
echo "Arguments are: ${*@Q}
```

...but with baseline POSIX sh, your best bet is probably to print each argument on a second line if you want to disambiguate:

```
echo "Arguments are:"
printf ' - %s\n' "$@"
```